# Perl: escape characters immediately adjacent to variables, inside double quotes

Tags: perl, escaping, rename, double-quotes

I've been trying to use perl's function `rename` in order to rename a large number of files. The problem I've encountered is that my variable `my $oldname` is made up from a name along the lines of variable, characters, variable, as in `my $oldname = "$variable1CHARACTERS$variable2.txt";`

I have used a multitude of options to escape the characters (single quotes, apostrophe, slash and loads of combinations) but it never works properly so renaming fails. Has anybody ever faced this problem? I think that the solution is through more double quotes, maybe put CHARACTERS under double quotes - but still haven't found a syntax that works. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like in the shell, you can use braces to delimit a variable name.

```
my $oldname = "${variable1}CHARACTERS${variable2}.txt";
```

The braces are not strictly necessary to disambiguate `$variable2` here (the period is not allowed in a variable name, so it has to end there) but you can use them just for symmetry.

In your limited scenario, you could also keep the strings separate, and join them:

```
my $oldname = join("", $variable1, "CHARACTERS", $variable2, ".txt");
```

Comment: Or simply `$variable1 . 'CHARACTERS' . $variable2`.

Comment: Thank you so much. After your answer I remembered I had used braces for the same purpose in a much older script I had written. Again thanks, greatly appreciated, there was no chance it would cross my mind, I was stuck with the forward slash and quotes.

Comment: @mscha Yeah, although I expect a single join to be more efficient than repeated dot pasting. Either is fine if you're not in a tight loop.

Comment: @tripleee: I tested it out, and in fact, `join` is the slowest solution.  It's about 10% slower than string contatenation.  The fastest solution is the interpolated version with braces, that's about 10% faster again.  (Tested with perl 5.22.0.)